# Why am I seeing high execution counts for the system stored procedure sys.sp_columns_managed

Tags: sql-server

We are seeing high wait times during business hours on one of our databases. Looking at SolarWinds I am finding that the system stored procedure 'sys.sp_columns_managed' is being executed more than 300,000 times per hour (according to SolarWinds). Has anyone else ever experienced this? Does anyone know what can be done to stop this? Or, am I not seeing things correctly in SolarWinds?

Comment: Does SolarWinds not tell you who / what app / what workstation/server is calling the stored procedure? Maybe profiler or a different monitoring tool could help out. (As for the calls, sounds like an infinite loop to me, I can't imagine what would need to call that procedure more than once, never mind at that rate).

Comment: I haven't been able to find anywhere in Solar Winds that gives me that information. I'll see if the powers that be will allow me to run profiler during the day on a production system. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an Extended event session to track the executions calls. This one is very efficient and will have minimal impact on the server.

It will track the first 5k calls (feel free to change the sample) and show additional info that should help you track the culprit.

- Client App Name
- Host name
- User name
- Client process id (PID)

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION ModuleStartFiltered
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_start
(
    ACTION
    (
        sqlserver.client_app_name
        , sqlserver.client_hostname
        , sqlserver.client_pid
        , sqlserver.is_system
        , sqlserver.server_instance_name
        , sqlserver.server_principal_name
        , sqlserver.tsql_stack
        , sqlserver.username
    )
    WHERE 
        object_name = N'sp_columns_managed' /* the order of conditions matters */
        AND package0.counter <= 5000 /* first 5k calls */           
)
ADD TARGET package0.event_file
(
    SET
        filename = N'ModuleStartFiltered'
        , max_file_size = 5 /* MB */
        , max_rollover_files = 2
)
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION [ModuleStartFiltered] ON SERVER STATE = START
```

There is also a chance this call might be nested - in that case, you can parse the TSQL Stack field - I write more about this in my blog post [Investigating Errors With Extended Events](https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/investigating-errors-with-extended-events/#analysing-the-errors)

Example of the output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This script below shows you the execution count of the stored procedures that are currently in your plan cache.

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) Execution_count
 FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
 where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
   group by cp.plan_handle, DB_NAME(st.dbid),
            OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), 
   OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by max(cp.usecounts) desc
```

That would be an starting point, if you could see the procedure there and from which database it is fired.

Then have a look who and what is using that particular database\calling that procedure.

[here you can find the code of the sys.sp_columns_managed stored procedure](http://pawjershauge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/spcolumnsmanaged-transact-sql-metadata.html).